# Calculating $\frac{\partial x }{\partial r}$ if $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am getting this $ \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} $ now im not so sure $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$ is zero . As r has affiliated $x $in it. Now if its zero then an physical interpretation would be great . If not then what is it ?

Comment: You could make use of Implicit Differentiation...
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}x^2+y^2+z^2,$$
which gives
$$2r=2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial r},$$
So that
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\frac{r}{x}-\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}-\frac{z}{x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine $\partial x/\partial r$, you need to know what are the other variables (besides $r$) that $x$ depends on.  One example is the ["spherical coordinates"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) change of variables...
\begin{align}
r &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\theta &= \arccos\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
\varphi &= \arctan\frac{y}{x}
\end{align}
and the inverse
\begin{align}
x &= r \sin \theta\cos \varphi\\
y &= r \sin \theta \sin \varphi\\
z &= r \cos \theta
\end{align}

When it is written out that way, can you find $\partial x/\partial r$?

The tricky thing is: there are other choices of additional variables, compatible with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, producing a different answer for $\partial x/\partial r$.

Comment: Do you want me to apply chain rule to get it?

Comment: $x = r \sin \theta\cos \varphi$ so $\partial x/\partial r = \sin \theta\cos \varphi$.

Comment: but in sin\theta term also i can do a partial like $\frac{\partial rsin\theta sin\phi}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} $.

Comment: Look up "chain rule for partial derivatives" in your calculus textbook.

Comment: as you said: https://study.com/academy/lesson/the-chain-rule-for-partial-derivatives.html

Answer (score 1):

If your expression is correct and you want to differentiate with respect to $r$, then solve for $x$ :

$$r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{r^2-y^2-z^2}$$

Recall that $(\sqrt{x})' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and that $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. Treat $-y^2-z^2$ as constants, **if** they are not depended by $r$ and then :

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(\sqrt{r^2-y^2-z^2}\Big) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{r^2-y^2-z^2}}\cdot(r^2)' = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2-z^2}}$$

Can you find the derivative for the case of the minus sign ?

This derivative can never be zero, except if  $$r=0 \implies x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0 \implies (x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$$
where you don't even have an $r$ parameter and that's just a $0=0$ equality.

**Note :** That's only for the case of $x,y,z$ being independed with respect to $r$ and $x$.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(\sqrt{r^2-y^2-z^2}\Big) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{r^2-y^2-z^2}}\cdot(r^2 -y^2-z^2)'$$ ?